# Why picture is moving from top of view to the middle part of screen in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, image, swiftui

I'm having a problem with `Image`. When I open my view I have my `Image` on the top of the screen, being "stuck" to the `NavigationBar`. The problem is that when I select any photo from library, the selected photo is displayed. However, it is not like it was in the beginning, on the top of view, but it is now in a completely different place, i.e. almost in the middle.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ScanWithPhotoFromLibrary: View {

    @State var cupWidth: String = ""
    @State var cupHeight: String = ""
    @State var stemLength: String = ""
    @State var leafWidth: String = ""
    @State var leafLength: String = ""

    @State private var showSheet: Bool = false
    @State private var showImagePicker: Bool = false
    @State private var sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType = .camera

    @State private var userImage: UIImage?
    @State private var flowerName: String = ""
    @EnvironmentObject var env: ImagePickerCoordinator

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView{
            VStack{
                Image(uiImage: userImage ?? UIImage(named: "flower_logo")!)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode:.fit)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
                    .frame(width: 375, height: 375)

            }

            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)

        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text(flowerName).foregroundColor(.blue), displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                HStack {
                    Button("Library") {
                        self.showImagePicker = true
                        self.sourceType = .photoLibrary
                        print("Library tapped!")
                       }
                   }
           )
           .sheet(isPresented: $showImagePicker) {
               ImagePicker(image: self.$userImage, isShown: self.$showImagePicker, flowerName: self.$flowerName, sourceType: self.sourceType)

           }
       }
}

struct ScanWithPhotoFromLibrary_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ScanWithPhotoFromLibrary()
    }
}
```

Above is my class where I display this Image.
What's wrong with the display?

Comment: Works fine here. Probably it is due to photos you selected in `aspectRatio(contentMode:.fit)` mode. Maybe you need .fill mode.

Comment: You'll probably want to add a `Spacer()` to the bottom of the `VStack` instead of setting the alignment of the `VStack` within the `NavigationView`. I'm not sure of the layout behavior of the `NavigationView` so I would not rely on it consuming the available screen space.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. As @Asperi wrote I changed aspectRatio for ```.fill``` and now works fine!